# What approach I should take to extract number entity from dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, spacy

I have the training, validation, and test dataset. The first column has store data and the second column has store numbers. I need to develop an entity extractor model which can extract store numbers from the first column. I tried searching about entity extractor models like SpaCy and Stanford NER package but did not quite understand how to implement them in this scenario.

[image: sample image data]

As you can see above, a store number is not always numeric data, but what I found out is that it always comes after the store name. If someone could share a reference link for this or any suggestions, please.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good case for RegEx string manipulation/extraction.